# Advise or Advice or Advice to?

Tags: grammar

In my opinion the following sentence should be like that:

> Support and advice partner institutions of Russia and Ukraine to
> define scenarios...

But a friend of mine feels confident that the sentence has to be like that:

> Support and advice to partner institutions of Russia and Ukraine to
> define scenarios...

Is it legitimate to use "to" in this sentence?

Comment: Okay, I guess both options are wrong.

"Support and advise partner institutions..." should be correct.

Comment: In general, there are some differences between AmE and BrE with -ce and -se word endings. In BrE the noun form usually ends in -ce and the verb form in -se, examples are advice/advise, licence/license but in AmE the noun form is very often (but not always) the same as the verb form, other examples are defense, practise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sentence is that you haven't given it in full. It doesn't (obviously) contain a subject, which may make it a sentence fragment. As such, it's not possible to tell what its meaning is.

There are multiple ways of writing your sentence. It depends on what you're trying to say:

> 1. **They are** support and advice partner institutions . . .

Here, both *support* and *advice* are nouns.

> 2. **They** support and advise partner institutions . . .

Here, both *support* and *advise* are verbs

> 3. **They offer** support and advice to partner institutions . . .

Here, *support* and *advice* are again nouns, but a verb has been added to the start of the sentence.

---

All three of those sentence constructions are fine. But without the subject, we don't know what your original sentence is trying to express.<sup>*</sup>

---

Note, however, that the final part of the sentence you give, *to define scenarios*, does not work with *any* of those constructions.

In simplified terms:

> ✘ 1. They are support institutions to define scenarios.
>   ✘ 2. They support institutions to define scenarios.
>   ✘ 3. They offer support to institutions to define scenarios.

You indicated in a comment under your question that "'support and advise partner institutions...' should be correct." This means that you consider the second sentence construction to be the sense you are trying to convey.

Given that, the following would make your sentence grammatical:

> ✔ **They** support and **advise** partner institutions of Russia and Ukraine **in the definition of** scenarios . . .

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that if this is actually an imperative sentence (it's not clear without more context), it actually *is* grammatical to leave out the initial *they*, because the subject *you* would be understood. But I have used *they* in order to clearly show the difference between the three different types of sentence.

Comment: "Here, both support and advice are nouns." They are [noun adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment!

The full sentence is:

Support and advise partner institutions of Russia and Ukraine, to define flood scenarios as input for the hydrodynamic model for the Dnieper river and its floodplains, for deriving precalculated inundation maps for these scenarios. 

Is it correct now? :)

Comment: @alex The complete sentence doesn't actually change my analysis or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

"Advice" is the noun for helpful, well-meaning information.

"Advise" is the verb - the act of giving advice.

You would use verb-subject for the latter, eg "*I advise you*", or "*I advise Russia*".

You can also use the verb *to give* when speaking about advice. If you specify to whom you are giving advice then you use "to", eg "*I gave advice to you*" or "*I give advice to Russia*".

Comment: Thank you very much. But in the case above I am not using the verb "to give". So how should I make use of it? 

I am completely confused now, what is grammatically correct here now